# General solution of equation: $\sin x + \sin 3x + \sin 5x = 0$. Pairing and taking sum in different ways yield different results.

Tags: trigonometry

Why is it that when you take $\sin x + (\sin3x + \sin5x)$, you get roots different from the ones when taking $(\sin x + \sin5x) + \sin3x$.

I've solved them using both methods, and when using $(\sin3x + \sin5x)$ way:
the roots are $n(\pi)$ and $n(\pi)\pm (2/3)\pi$

Whereas when using $(\sin x + \sin5x)$ way:
the roots are $n\pi/3$ and the other one same as above (i.e. $n(\pi)\pm (2/3)\pi$ )

I've seen mention of this question here before, it was left unanswered so I'm here.

My solution:

$\sin x+\sin3x+\sin5x = 0$

$2\sin3x\cos2x+\sin3x = 0$

$\sin3x(2\cos2x + 1) = 0$

$$ x = n\pi /3 \text{  or } x = n \pi \pm  \pi /3 $$

but when

$\sin x+ (\sin3x+\sin5x) = 0$

$\sin x + 2\sin4x\cos x = 0 $

$\sin x  + 8\sin x\cos2x (\cos x)^2$

$(\sin x)(8 ((2\cos x)^2  - 1)(\cos x) ^2$

$\sin x((4(\cos x)^2 - 1))^2 = 0$

which will yield solutions as

$$x = n\pi\;\text{ or }\;n\pi \pm \pi/3$$

Comment: How on earth can we tell you where you went wrong, if you don't show us your working?

Comment: Show your work, so we see the issue

Comment: alright please wait a second

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I don't know how to currently... it would take sometime for me to learn that, i'm extremely sorry...

Comment: It will make your post easier to read. Put mathematical expressions in dollar signs and use backslashes before sin, cos, pi, e.g. `$\sin x$` produces $\sin x$

Comment: Have you tried substituting your answers into the original problem (this might help you figure out where a solution goes wrong).

Comment: Please fill in the "solving it further part".  Without that, it's hard to follow your work.

Comment: You can obtain $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ by typing `$\sin x$` and `$\cos x$` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you miss it;

- $n\pi=3n\cdot\frac{\pi}{3}$
- $n\pi\pm\frac{\pi}{3}=(3n\pm1)\cdot\frac{\pi}{3}$

So both of the sets you get are actually identical which is an integer multiple of $\frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: i am getting a factor of $sinx$ in on and $sin3x$ in another which means i am facing the problem in general solution as x = n.$pi$ or n($pi$)/3

Comment: @Stupidunderneath I don't understand. You posted the question as if you got two different solutions but both of your solutions are identical.

Comment: no i'm getting two different solutions, n$pi$ in one and n($pi$)/3 in another

Comment: @Stupidunderneath No. You get $n\pi$ OR $n\pi \pm\frac{\pi}{3}$ in one and $n\frac{\pi}{3}$ OR $n\pi \pm\frac{\pi}{3}$ in another.

Comment: n$pi$ and n($pi/3$) aren't different, given that n is an integer?

Comment: @Stupidunderneath, both of your solutions can more economically be expressed as "all integer multiples of $\pi/3$".

Comment: @TonyK ooooh, i got ittt!!!, thank you very much!!

Comment: @Stupidunderneath let me ask you, is (a or (b or c)) not the same as ((a or b or c) or (b or c)) because a is not the same as (a or b or c)? You think you get two different solutions because you compare part of one solution to part of the other solution

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja well i thought if n is an integer the npi cannot be equal to npi/3 becuase it would require rational numbers to do so, then got confused, that cleared it up for me, thank you.